# Fazer várias div's fixed

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Como fazer para que ao desaparecer uma div todas "fiquem no sitio" em que estão. Deixo abaixo um exemplo para ser mais esclarecedor.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
     if($("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).is(":visible")){
         $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).fadeOut("slow");
        } else {
         $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div{
     /* position: ???;  Já exprimentei vários values mas nada... 
      Já não sei o que pôr */
        margin-left: 5%;
     margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="1">Click me 1!</button>
  <p id="p1">Click to disappear 1.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="2">Click me 2!</button>
  <p id="p2">Click to disappear 2.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="3">Click me 3!</button>
  <p id="p3">Click to disappear 3.</p>
 </div>
```

Este foi um pequeno exemplo que criei para testar. O que queria é que as div's mantivessem o mesmo tamanho após o click do button. 
Já tentei com position mas não há maneira de elas ficarem sossegadas...

PS: Gostaria de saber o que estou a fazer errado, não apenas a resposta para o meu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce diz assim?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    var tamanho = $(this).parent().height();
    
    $(this).parent().css('height', tamanho+'px')
    
    
  
    
    //alert(tamanho)
 if($("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).is(":visible")){
     $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).fadeOut("slow");
    } else {
     $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
});
```

```css
div{
     /* position: ???;  Já exprimentei vários values mas nada... 
      Já não sei o que pôr */
        margin-left: 5%;
     margin-top: 5%;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="1">Click me 1!</button>
  <p id="p1">Click to disappear 1.dsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadasdsadasdasdasdasdsa</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="2">Click me 2!</button>
  <p id="p2">Click to disappear 2.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="3">Click me 3!</button>
  <p id="p3">Click to disappear 3.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sim, mas só mesmo dando uma height é que funciona? Pois aqui tem as 3 o mesmo tamanho mas no site que estou a trabalhar elas tem diferentes tamanhos que não se sabe quanto (tudo depende do que se escrever e adicionar nelas)

Comment: mas ai da pra fazer um bem bolado com `jQuery`, vou fazer um exemplo

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Editei o codigo